# Sequence of positive integers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> An infinite sequence of increasing positive integers is given with bounded first differences.
>
> Prove that there are elements $a$ and $b$ in the sequence such that $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is a positive integer.

I think maybe computing the [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of the sequence would lead to some contradiction. But don't know if it exists.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean by "bounded first differences" that there is a constant difference between any two consecutive terms?

Comment: @YourIDE I mean that if $x_{n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the sequence, then the sequence $d_{n} = x_{n+1} - x_{n}$ is [bounded above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158694/definition-of-a-bounded-sequence).

Comment: This seems to me mre of a combinatorial problem..An application of pigeonhole principle maybe?

Comment: @MariosGretsas I was thinking something along the lines of density of such numbers.

Comment: @Henry i only think that such a sequence has alternating differences like $1,4,5,8 ... $ because when the difference is incessantly increasing it would diverge to infinite , hence not bounded.

Comment: @Idle That's trivial, as stated by MooS in deleted answer. There will be a difference $d$ which will occur infinite times.

Comment: yes, or many. and this is a large open gate to the evidence. and i agree with @marios that it is likely a pigeonhole problem.

Comment: @Henry That approach will definitely work: it is a famous result of Erdős that if $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers which don't divide one another, then $\sum_n 1/(a_n \log a_n)$ converges (in fact, is bounded).  This certainly can't happen if $\{a_n\}$ has positive lower density.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? The context may give an indication as to which tools are needed.

Comment: this problem can be solved just if we prove that a sequence or combination of $n$ unordered integers repeat more or equal to a defined $k$ times **consequently**.

Comment: This is more like an itinerary in a graph, if it is proved that someone walking infinitely in a graph, he would have to take a similar walk from $u$ to $v$ sequentially $k$ or more definite times from a definite timemark.

Comment: @MariosGretsas One subtlety here is that the result does depend crucially on the sequence extending to infinity.  The finite sequence $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\}$ has very bounded gaps and very high density ($\tfrac12$), but doesn't contain any dividing pairs.  This suggests there has to be some aspect of any proof that uses some global consideration.

Comment: @ErickWong indeed the proof doesn't come from discret mathematics, the concept of infinity must be included and i was searching around any evidence that approaching infinity, an arbitrary sequence ${a_0,a_1,..a_n}$ must be reiterated unorderly at some point, i don't know how to prove that.

Answer (score 14):

[Here is a 1935 paper](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1935-04.pdf) of a relatively young Erdős proving in a few lines that a sequence of positive integers which don't divide one another must have lower density zero, as a consequence of the fact that $\sum_n 1/(a_n \log a_n)$ is bounded by an absolute constant.  In particular, a sequence with gaps bounded by $d$ has lower density $\ge 1/d$, so this proves the claim, but perhaps there is a more direct argument.  The bounded gap requirement does handily eliminate any possibility of a Besicovitch-type construction (which yields a positive upper density, but introduces gaps which grow very rapidly in length).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the reference! I'll keep this question open and perhaps add a bounty since I think there might be more approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I have doubts about the effeciency of this proof attempt, but it is just an extension of @MooS 's answer that is based upon the fact that [increasing prime gaps](https://oeis.org/A005250) are diverging to infinity, and [they are!](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html):

> The proof in the paper claims that for an arbitrary large $n$ there is a sequence $n!,n!+2,n!+3,n!+4....n!+n=n!,2(n!/2+1),3(n!/3+1)...$ of composite numbers intermediating the largest prime $p_0$ before $n$ and the nearest $p_1$ after $n!+n$ which converges respectively of larger $n$.

On this ground you should remark that picking up consecutive primes iterately will force us into a pitfall! what is it ? it's like a cul-de-sac after consecutive leaps over prime gaps it should exist some infinitely divergent one when you have to choose a composite number as forced to be bound to some limit of differences.

What if a range of primes are skipped ? The following numbers should be mutually  indivisible written in the form of skipped prime numbers. $p_0^ip_1^j...$ in the forthcoming must have decreasing prime weights, which means descending sets of {i,j..} thus they wouldn't divide their previous. Which immediately indicates that picking up a composite $p_0^ip_1^jp_2^k$ for example must consequently lead to a following $p_0^{i'}p_1^{j'}p_2^{k'}\prod_l p_l^l$ where $i+j+k>i'+j'+k'$.

Let's denote a *prime quotient*: a ratio between two composite mutually indivisible numbers chosen consequently. The prime quotient between the two previous composites is $\frac{p_0^{i'}p_1^{j'}p_2^{k'}\prod_l p_l^l}{p_0^ip_1^jp_2^k}$ their values are continuously increasing. The only steady sequence that guarantees a smallest prime quotient is $p_jp_{j+1}$ the prime quotient is ultimately small which equals $\frac{p_{j+2}}{p_j}$, consequently the gap between them $p_{j+1}(p_{j+2}-p_{j})$ is divergent.

I was planning to check my claims with an exhaustive sweepment program but there is already a [handful here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148999/different-ways-of-defining-primes) by which one can ensure that increasing n-prime gaps are also divergent.

Comment: This argument is nearly incomprehensible.  What does "it's like a cul-de-sac after consecutive leaps over prime gaps it should exist some infinitely divergent one when you have to choose a composite number as forced to be bound to some limit of differences" even refer to?  What's the context?  What's wrong with choosing a composite number?  The sequence need not even contain a single prime.  The link about $n$-prime gaps is also of only mild relevance since the sequence need not be chosen greedily.

Comment: @ErickWong a composite number in a sense of a product between an already chosen number with an arbitrary composite/prime number. a cul-de-sac is a situation when you are limited to not extend your choice more than a definite bound $n$, which force us to opt for a composite number = a divisible number by a previous one.

Comment: @ErickWong I just think of it as an attempt, it doesn't prove anything since there dosn't exist any mathematical notation to define where a deadlock can occur, even with a steady sequence of chosen numbers, prime gaps are random, unexpected, I don't think that anyone can maybe even bind a cul-de-sac situation to a range of inequalities, Only i conjectured that this situation must happen at some point because prime gaps doesn't converge!